# Adding languages in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using `VS Code Editor`.

In:

> Code --> Preferences --> User Settings

I want to add Handlebars. In the array I added "hbs"

```
"beautify.language": {
        "js": {
            "type": [enter code here
                "javascript",
                "json"
            ],
            "filename": [
                ".jshintrc",
                ".jsbeautify"
            ]
        },
        "css": [
            "css",
            "scss"
        ],
        "html": [
            "htm",
            "html",
            "hbs"
        ]
    }
}
```

But it's not working, How can I set hbs language for beautify?

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Is `.hbs` a file extension you want to format as HTML?

Comment: so .hbs is handlebars. I'm not sure if templating languages fall under the html object or get it's own.